# fprintf causes device to crash but not simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, io, ipod-touch

I have an iPod touch running iOS 4.2.1, and a simulator running iOS 4.2. In the simulator, my code works just fine, but on the device, it crashes.

The code in question is:

```
FILE *file = fopen([[@"niplot/" stringByAppendingString:text_field.text] fileSystemRepresentation], "w");
...
fprintf(file, "%s", [print_str UTF8String]); //crash occurs here, EXC BAD ACCESS
...
fclose(file);
```

Could it have something to do with the file or folder not existing? The simulator created them for me in this case. I'd try to create the files and folders manually on the device, but I'm not sure how. Also, I've tried the file names with and without a .txt extension.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not use the native file handling mechanisms?

Comment: What native file handling mechanisms? I couldn't find any, and also I'm used to using C's file API.

Comment: it's not your printf that's the problem, it's `fopen`, it's a relative path name, and the device is more strictly sandboxed than the simulator (also the launching directories may be different for the two)

Comment: On developer.apple.com there are a complete list of APIs for iphone/ipod file handling (start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/LowLevelFileMgmt/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [some examples](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/using-the-document-directory-to-store-files)  of file save/load/delete.